# What is difference between directional derivative and gradient?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

What is difference between the directional derivative $\frac{df(r)}{dr}$ and the gradient $\nabla f(r)$ of a function $f$?

Comment: The former is a scalar, that gives the rate of change of $f$ in the direction $r$; the latter is a vector, that gives the direction in which $f$ is increasing most quickly.

Comment: To add, note that under some mild conditions, the directional derivative in direction $\vec{s}$ is $\vec{s} \cdot \nabla f(r)$.